# Using HoloEverywhere library

Tags: android, git, android-holo-everywhere

I'm new to using other libraries, but the current project that I am working on is using this HoloEverywhere library. Unfortunately, no files were given to me from that library, so I had to download it myself. I cloned git repository, but when I add HoloEverywhere folder to my Eclipse workspace, I get tons of error messages that look like this:

```
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:662: error: Resource entry Holo.Theme already has bag item textAppearanceListItemSmall. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:638: Originally defined here. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values-v14\styles.xml:61: error: Resource entry Holo.Theme already has bag item textAppearanceListItemSmall. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values-v14\styles.xml:37: Originally defined here. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:602: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock'. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:667: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'activatedBackgroundIndicator'. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:615: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'dividerVertical'. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:650: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'dropDownListViewStyle'. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:616: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'dropdownListPreferredItemHeight'. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:652: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'listPopupWindowStyle'. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:621: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'listPreferredItemHeightSmall'. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:680: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'listPreferredItemPaddingLeft'. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:681: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'listPreferredItemPaddingRight'. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:654: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'selectableItemBackground'. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:655: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'spinnerDropDownItemStyle'. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:656: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'spinnerItemStyle'. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:660: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textAppearanceLargePopupMenu'. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:638: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textAppearanceListItemSmall'. 
[2012-12-08 13:46:51 - HoloEverywhere Demo] D:\Downloads\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\styles.xml:663: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu'.
```

It appears that I'm missing some files and there are some redefinitions going on, but I have no Idea how to solve this problem. Tried reading their wiki, but with my current understanding, I can't get anything useful out of it.

What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT]
While using git, I was unable to follow this step:

```
git clone git://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere.git HoloEverywhere
cd HoloEverywhere
git submodule --init --recursive update
```

On last part I get this error:
[image]

I use msysgit and for the first part I manage to download files, but I can't carry on with updates so I guess my first problem is there. Can I use some other command? I don't have any prior experience with git.

[EDIT2]
I installed Ubuntu just to check if it was some problems with windows version of git, but no, I still get error on this line:

> git submodule --init --recursive update

Comment: did you add `Android Support Library` ?

Comment: No, I didn't do that myself. Should I copy android-support-v4.jar to my project libs directory or to one of the projects that were created after importing HoloEverywhere? P. S. Thanks Pearson, for more readable edit.

Comment: no, just right click on your project in eclipse, and then `android-tools` then `add support library`.

Comment: I added support to my project and to HoloEverywhere projects, but that didn't helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I lacked experience with git.
I don't know why the author has written the command like this:

> git submodule --init --recursive update

But on linux and windows I had to enter:

> git submodule init

and

> git submodule update --recursive